# Passing multiple data through to next scene

Tags: react-native

I'm lost as to how to send through multiple input of data through to the next scene in my app. I have no problem with sending through one input of data "text1".

This is my sample code below.

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text1: '',
      text2: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <View>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              onChangeText={text1 => this.setState({ text1 })}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              onChangeText={text2 => this.setState({ text2 })}
            />
          </View>

          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.btnNext}
            onPress={this.onPressNext.bind(this)}>
            <Text style={styles.btnText}>Next</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

Below is where i think needs fixing because the + sign isn't allowing to pass two states?

```
  onPressNext() {
    Actions.scene2({text1: this.state.text1} +
    {text2: this.state.text2});
}
}
```

Comment: Can't you send it as one object?

Comment: How would i do that when i have two separate inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to pass 2 different objects, just pass it like:

```
Actions.scene2({text1: this.state.text1,
 text2: this.state.text2})
```